# How to create a function to retrieve all children's id from a nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration, children

I want to retrieve all child ids of a specific group, which can be deeply nested or not.

Here is a sample json:

```
[
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Desjardins Group 1',
        children: [
          { id: 2, name: 'Analysts', children: [] },
          { id: 3, name: 'Administration', children: [] }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Desjardins Group 2',
        children: [
          { id: 5, name: 'Consultants1', children: [] },
          {
            id: 6,
            name: 'Consultant2',
            children: [
              {
                id: 7, name: 'Interns', children: [
                  { id: 8, name: 'subInterns1', children: [] },
                  { id: 9, name: 'subInterns2', children: [] },
                  { id: 10, name: 'subInterns3', children: [] }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I'm trying to make a function that takes an id has a parameter, and return all child ids.
Ex: getChildGroups(6) would return 7, 8, 9 and 10.

I guess recursive function and filters are the way to go, but i can't find a proper example.

Comment: You have to share us what you already tried in order for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of Johann Bauer's answer.

The first function just finds the first node that matches the given ID, with no need for any accumulation of data:

```
function findNode(data, id) {
    if (!Array.isArray(data)) return;

    for (let entry of data) {
        if (entry.id === id) {
            return entry;
        } else {
            const node = findNode(entry.children, id);
            if (node) { 
                return node;    
            }           
        }       
    }   
}
```

This second function just gets the child IDs, storing them in the passed array, without any intermediate arrays being created:

```
function getChildIds(node, result = []) {
    if (!node) return;
    if (!Array.isArray(node.children)) return;

    for (let entry of node.children) {
        result.push(entry.id);
        getChildIds(entry, result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea to split your problem into two smaller problems:

1. Find a group of ID x somewhere nested in the graph
2. Given a node, return all their sub-node IDs recursively

The solution to the first problem could look something like this:

```
function findGroupId(o, id) {
    if (o.id == id) {
        // We found it!
        return o;
    }

    if (Array.isArray(o)) {
        // If we start with a list of objects, pretend it is the root node
        o = {children: o}
    }

    let results = [];
    for (let c of o.children) {
        // recursively call this function again
        results.push(findGroupId(c, id))
    }

    // return the first matching node
    return results.filter(r => r !== undefined)[0];
}
```

And for the second problem:

```
function getAllChildrenIDs(o) {
    if (o.children === undefined)
        return [];

    let ids = [];

    for (c of o.children) {
        ids.push(c.id);
        // recursively call this function again
        for (id of getAllChildrenIDs(c))
            ids.push(id);
    }
    return ids;
}
```

And if we put this together:

```js
let example = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Desjardins Group 1',
    children: [{
        id: 2,
        name: 'Analysts',
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Administration',
        children: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Desjardins Group 2',
    children: [{
        id: 5,
        name: 'Consultants1',
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        name: 'Consultant2',
        children: [{
          id: 7,
          name: 'Interns',
          children: [{
              id: 8,
              name: 'subInterns1',
              children: []
            },
            {
              id: 9,
              name: 'subInterns2',
              children: []
            },
            {
              id: 10,
              name: 'subInterns3',
              children: []
            }
          ]
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
];

function findGroupId(o, id) {
  if (o.id == id) {
    return o;
  }

  if (Array.isArray(o)) {
    o = {
      children: o
    }
  }

  let results = [];
  for (let c of o.children) {
    results.push(findGroupId(c, id))
  }

  return results.filter(r => r !== undefined)[0];
}

function getAllChildrenIDs(o) {
  if (o.children === undefined)
    return [];
  let ids = [];
  for (c of o.children) {
    ids.push(c.id);
    for (id of getAllChildrenIDs(c))
      ids.push(id);
  }
  return ids;
}

console.log(getAllChildrenIDs(findGroupId(example, 6)))
```

Comment: I think that your first function is unnecessarily complicated - it just needs to recurse until it finds the desired ID, and then stop.   There's no need to accumulate any sort of result array.    Your second function would probably also be better if it accumulated into a passed array, instead of creating a new one at each stage of the recursion.

Comment: @AInitak I initially had a structure in mind where different elements share the same ID but left that out for simplicity. Your version is far more elegant.